# How to document Excel Power Query steps?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, documentation, power-query, comments

I have an Excel 2016 spreadsheet that has a Power Query sheet in it. The query is used for transforming data.

The query has multiple steps.

- While some of the steps are straight forward, others are not so straightforward, and it can be hard to remember what the rationale was behind them.

---

[image]

[image]

---

Is there a way to document the Power Query steps with some sort of note, etc.?

Comment: Yeah, it's called a notebook. These days notebooks can be electronic. I use one all the time :)

Comment: You can also add comments to the code in the `Advanced Editor`

Comment: Related: [Adding Tooltips To Column Headers In The Power Query Editor In Power BI And Excel](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2020/07/19/adding-tooltips-to-column-headers-in-the-power-query-editor-in-power-bi-and-excel/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I can right-click a step and go to *Properties* and enter a Description.

[image]

I could edit step's *Name* to make it more meaningful.

---

And as @RonRosenfeld mentioned:

> You can also add comments to the code in the Advanced Editor.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by @User1973, you can put comments in the Advanced Editor.  A newer feature (maybe after the question was asked) is that an icon will appear in the APPLIED STEPS list to indicate a comment is available and hovering over it will reveal the comment.

[image]